# Genesis Style Selector causes PHP warning

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I am creating my own child theme using the Genesis framework. I have added custom color options, via the function:

```
 add_theme_support( 'genesis-style-selector', array(
   'theme-blue' => __( 'Blue', 'themename' ),
   'theme-green'    => __( 'Green', 'themename' )
 ) );
```

If I use this from the WP Admin and Genesis -> Theme Settings it works fine. However, when I open the customizer I get a PHP warning.

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in D:...\wp-content\themes\genesis\lib\admin\customizer.php on line 111

This is the piece of code around line 111. Line 111 is the one that starts with array_shift(...

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
        'genesis_color_scheme',
        array(
            'label'    => __( 'Select Color Style', 'genesis'),
            'section'  => 'genesis_color_scheme',
            'settings' => $this->get_field_name( 'style_selection' ),
            'type'     => 'select',
            'choices'  => array_merge(
                array( '' => __( 'Default', 'genesis' ) ),
                array_shift( get_theme_support( 'genesis-style-selector' ) )
            ),
        )
    );
```

What causes this warning? And how do I make it go away without changing Genesis core files?

Comment: Any reason you can't post this on the SP forums or SP technical support? Hard to test for people who don't own the theme and its not publicly accessible.

Comment: I should probably post it there too, it just seems there's no appropriate forum for it. There's just "General discussions" and "Design tips & tricks" that has anything to do with the themes and neither seemed appropriate for my question. I do intend to send them an e-mail, though.

Comment: It's definitely a question for SP technical support via the contact form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should remove the warning

```
$selector = get_theme_support( 'genesis-style-selector' );
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'genesis_color_scheme',
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Select Color Style', 'genesis'),
        'section'  => 'genesis_color_scheme',
        'settings' => $this->get_field_name( 'style_selection' ),
        'type'     => 'select',
        'choices'  => array_merge(
            array( '' => __( 'Default', 'genesis' ) ),
            array_shift( $selector )
        ),
    )
);
```